# uploadify.js get id of clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I need to retreive the ID of the button that is clicked to launch file upload with uploadify(). I the have to parse the ID to extract a number from it and pass this on to my upload.php script. The format of the id would be :

```
upload_1
upload_2
.....
upload_XX
```

The button (divs) are being created in PHP with:

```
while (....) {
    echo "<div class='upload' id='upload_" . $row['did'] . "' data-role='none' title='UPLOAD DOCUMENTS'>";
}
```

I need to retreive the `XX` (`$row['did']`) part.

This is the script that I have:

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
$(function() {
    $('div[id*="upload_"]').uploadify({
        'buttonText'    : '&#x21e7;',
        'method'            : 'POST',
        'uploadLimit'  : 2,
        'width'             : 24,
        'height'        : 24,
        'title'         : 'UPLOAD DOCS',
        'buttonClass'   : 'uploadbutton',
        'swf'           : 'inc/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader'      : 'inc/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadStart': function (file, event) {
                alert($(this).attr("id"))
                $(this).uploadify('settings','formData',{
                    'driver': $(this).attr("id").toString().replace('upload_',''),
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
                })
        }
    });
});
```

console.log output:

```
n.fn.init[1]0: SWFUploadbutton: n.fn.init[1]bytesLoaded: 0customSettings: ObjecteventQueue: Array[0]movieElement: object#SWFUpload_0.swfuploadmovieName: "SWFUpload_0"original: n.fn.init[1]queue: n.fn.init[1]queueData: Objectsettings: Objecttimer: 1433418517151wrapper: n.fn.init[1]__proto__: SWFUploadlength: 1__proto__: n[0]
```

Comment: what you are getting for `alert($(this).attr("id"))`??

Comment: empty value "" (not undefined)

Comment: Give us output of `console.log($(this))` from your console.

Comment: Can you describe in detail what issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Ids = new Array();

 $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': SWFUrl,
        'script': AshxUrl,
        'cancelImg': cancelUrl,
        'folder': uploadsUrl,
        'auto': true,
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.psd;*.jpeg',
        'fileDesc': 'Graphics Files',
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'buttonText': 'Upload PSD',
        'multi': true,
        'queueID': 'divParent',
        'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            Ids.push(response);
        },
'onSelect': function (event, ID, fileObj)
        {

            alert(event.target);
            alert($(event.target).prop('id'));
            customFileArray.push({ id: ID, file: fileObj, upload: false });
        }
    });
```

To get Value call following code.

```
 $("#Ids").val(Ids.join(','));
```

just omit unwanted code that I have used , I think this is enough for your understanding

let me know if you still have issue

Comment: I need to get the ID before the `onComplete` event

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni at Which Time or event ?

Comment: When I click on the button I need to know the id of the button I clicked.

Comment: You need id's of file being uploaded or the btn which you have clicked to open file upload ?

Comment: Of the button that I clicked to upload

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni Check this updated answer with onSelect event , You will get it here ..